# SVG path is rendered differently when imported into PaperJS

Tags: svg, paperjs

I am trying to copy a SVG path from a SVG file to use in a PaperJS project.

Here is a [Paper.JS Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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) of the SVG using `new Path(svgPath)`

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ewme0jqt/) of how it's supposed to look

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pathData contains two subpaths (i.e. outside of character, inside hole). When dealing with multiple subpaths in PaperJS, I believe you need to use CompoundPath instead of Path. In your PaperJS example, change...

```
var path = new Path(pathData);
```

to...

```
var path = new CompoundPath(pathData);
```